# Sql Script file (apex_epg_config.sql) is missing in Oracle Apex 20.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-20.1

I have Oracle Apex 20.1 Installed on Oracle Linux 6.10 Server with Oracle Database 12.2. Recently I am trying to update into Apex 20.2 but this script file (apex_epg_config.sql) is missing in zip folder.

When I load the site then giving me this error:

```
There is a problem with your environment because the Application Express files are not up-to-date! The 
files for version 20.1.0.00.13 have been loaded, but 20.2.0.00.20 is expected. Please verify that you 
have copied the images directory to your application server as instructed in the Installation Guide.
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

The embedded PL/SQL Gateway (EPG) along with mod_plsql are no longer supported for Oracle APEX.  This deprecation [was announced](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-12877F22-DA1F-45F2-91D9-103817AD659A) in APEX 20.1.

Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) is the only supported and documented Web listener for APEX.  The configuration instructions are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/htmig/installing-and-configuring-apex-and-ords.html#GUID-8EE981AD-B1F9-46C2-BB5A-C9FE60CCD4AA).  ORDS includes an embedded Web server, so in addition to being supported with Apache Tomcat and WebLogic Server, you can also run ORDS standalone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading from APEX 18.2 to 20.2. I solved the problem by not executing this script. It seems that it isn't needed any longer. Update succeeded without running this script.
Attention: There is a pitfall: After upgrading you must clear your browser cache (only images). When I cleared the browser cache, the error message disappeared.