# SP2-0310: unable to open file "apex_epg_config.sql"

Tags: database, oracle-apex, oracle19c

Hi I have installed Apex on Oracle 19c pluggable database. I have also successfully run the apex_rest_config command. But when I try to configure pl/sql gateway with the command @apex_epg_config.sql Path_to_apexfolder It gives the following error
SP2-0310: unable to open file "apex_epg_config.sql"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql Script file (apex\_epg\_config.sql) is missing in Oracle Apex 20.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64498724/sql-script-file-apex-epg-config-sql-is-missing-in-oracle-apex-20-2)

Comment: @EJEgyed But I cannot open localhost:8080/apex in browser. Its asking for username and password. Even tried to change port. .

Comment: Starting in APEX 20.1, the pl/sql gateway was deprecated which is why the script is missing. You will need to use ORDS as that is the only supported web listener for APEX. See Joel's answers in the linked question.